# universal windows phone-background task stop

Tags: triggers, win-universal-app, background-task

As I understand the background task is pretty similar to the "Service" in android.
I try to run some code in the background even when the app got suspended.
I used this register code:

```
   var exampleTaskName = "ExampleBackgroundTask";       
        builder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder();
        builder.Name = exampleTaskName;
        TimeTrigger timer = new TimeTrigger(10, false);
        builder.TaskEntryPoint = "RuntimeComponent1.ExampleBackgroundTask";
        builder.SetTrigger(timer);
        builder.Register();
```

and when I debug the run method of the background task,sometimes it hits sometime neither.
I get this error sometimes on the TimeTrigger timer=new TimerTrigger(10,false):

> Additional information: Value does not fall within the expected range.

Comment: I think that the minimum trigger time for a background task is 15 minutes. Try to add some more minutes.

Comment: and if I want to start the background task immediately?

Comment: and even when I change it the run method not always executes

Comment: You cannot run *TimeTrigger* task right away, it will be fired with the closest tick to the value you have set.

Comment: Maybe another trigger type? is there any way to start background task without trigger?